# MuPDF :: pagination of the output is somewhat messed up: no more linearity but 1,2,3,5,4

Tags: linux, mupdf

issues with Mutool and MuP

running this on MX-Linux: I'm trying to work with the latest release  of MuPDF library.

if i a the document into pieces (A 5) then i get fancy results: the number of the pages (the pagination) does fulle get lost..

1,4,3,2,5, and so forth

btw: see the commands i run:

```
mutool poster -x 2 input.pdf output.pdf
```

states that the document should be divided into two parts in the X axis.
The cutting axis is accordingly in the middle from top to bottom, so that two equal sides are created on the left and right.

You can split a document into individual pages with pdftk

```
pdftk input.pdf burst
```

we can find the output files in the same directory as pg_0001.pdf, pg_0002.pdf etc

what goes wrong here!?

see the datset - https://www.file-upload.net/download-14207207/__0_100__20200413204027.pdf.html

what is wanted: i want to cut this into A5 :: note: the A5-Formate is 148 mm width and 210 mm height

i use the commands from these ressources:
https://www.mankier.com/1/mupdf
https://mupdf.com/docs/

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue here when trying to split a scanned pdf in 4 pages per page.

In my case, the offending pages are those that have been rotated.

It seems that somehow the pdf file knows it's been rotated and mutool ignores this. I solved it first printing the file to a new pdf file so that it forgets about the rotation, then mutool works fine.

I used unovonv as it was inside a script:

unoconv -f pdf -o output.pdf input.pdf

Comment: hello dear jose - great to hear from you: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/mupdf-pagination-of-the-output-is-messed-up-no-linearity-1235476-a-4175679523/


- qpdf was able to resolve the issues..
- i guess that i will have to do further readings in the qpdf-man-pages

btw
Mupdf created a booklet-printing-order - like described here cf. https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/ways-print-pdfs.html

i guess that i runned certain MuPDF-commands and subsequently i got back this order. llook forward to hear from you again Jose!!

Comment: dear jose - it would  be great if you can answer again - and comment the above mentioned ideas and thoughts. Look forward to hear from you. Regards - zero